How to render new navigation based on admin/client Vue.js
I m currently working on a e-commerce website and i started to make the admin pages (dashboard , CRM , Products etc). I have a navigation set for the main page ( e.g. Home , About us , Shop , Profile etc) and i need to have a separate navigation showed only for the admin pages or for the all admin endpoints. How to do that ?
Relevant pieces of code : These is index.js in vue-router
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import IndexPage from '../components/IndexPage.vue'
import RegisterPage from '../components/UserLogInAnRegister/RegisterPage.vue'
import LoginPage from '../components/UserLogInAnRegister/LoginPage.vue'
import ConfirmationPage from '../components/UserHelpers/Confirmation.vue'
import ForgotPasswordPage from '../components/UserHelpers/ForgotPassword.vue'
import EmailForForgotPasswordPage from '../components/UserHelpers/EmailForForgotPassword.vue'
import LogoutPage from '../components/UserHelpers/LogoutPage.vue'
import ProfilePage from '../components/UserData/ProfilePage.vue'
import PersonalProfilePage from '../components/UserData/PersonalData.vue'
import ChangingDataConfirmation from '../components/UserHelpers/ChangingAccountData.vue'
import AdressesData from '../components/UserData/AddressesData.vue'
import OrdersData from '@/components/UserData/OrdersData.vue'
import ProductsData from '@/components/Products/ProductsMainPage.vue'
import AdminLogin from '@/components/AdminPages/AdminLogin.vue'
import AdminDashboard from '@/components/AdminPages/AdminDashboard.vue'
import store from '@/store'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'index',
    component: IndexPage
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'index',
    component: IndexPage
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    name: 'register',
    component: RegisterPage
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: 'login',
    component: LoginPage
  },
  {
    path: "/confirmare/:token",
    name: "confirmation",
    component: ConfirmationPage
  },
  {
    path: "/forgotpassword/:token",
    name: "forgotpassword",
    component: ForgotPasswordPage
  },
  {
    path: "/forgotpassword",
    name: "emailForForgotPassword",
    component: EmailForForgotPasswordPage
  },
  {
    path: "/logout",
    name: "LogoutPage",
    component: LogoutPage
  },
  {
    path: "/profile",
    name: "ProfilePage",
    component: ProfilePage
  },
  {
    path: "/profile/data",
    name: "PersonalProfileData",
    component: PersonalProfilePage
  },
  {
    path: "/account/changeEmail/:token",
    name: "ChangingAccountData",
    component: ChangingDataConfirmation
  },
  {
    path: "/profile/addresses",
    name: "Adresses",
    component: AdressesData
  },
  {
    path: "/profile/orders",
    name: "Orders",
    component: OrdersData
  },
  {
    path: "/shop",
    name: "ProductsMainPage",
    component: ProductsData
  },
  {
    path: "/admin/login",
    name: "AdminLogin",
    component: AdminLogin,
    meta: {requiresAuth: true,requiresAdmin: true},
  },
  {
    path: "/admin/dashboard",
    name: "AdminDashboard",
    component: AdminDashboard,
    meta: {requiresAuth: true,requiresAdmin: true},
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isAuth = store.getters.isAuthenticated;
  const isAdmin = store.getters.isAdmin;

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth && record.meta.requiresAdmin)) {
    if (isAuth && isAdmin) {
      next();
    } else {
      next({ name: 'login' });
    }
  } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (isAuth) {
      next();
    } else {
      next({ name: 'login' });
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});


export default router

This is the AdminNavBar.vue
<template>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-if="sidebar" @click="toggleSidebar()" app>
        <v-list-item title="Administrare Texx"></v-list-item>
        <v-list 
        center >
            <v-list-item v-for="item in navAdminItems" 
            :key="item.title" 
            :to="item.path"
            :title="item.title">
            <v-icon center>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                {{ item.title }}
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    name: 'AdminNavBar',
    data(){
        return {
            sidebar: false,
            navAdminItems: [
                {title: 'Dashboard' , path:'/admin/dashboard' , icon:'mdi-monitor-dashboard'},
                {title: 'Produse' , path:'/admin/products', icon:'mdi-cart'},
                {title: 'Clienti' , path:'/admin/customers', icon:'mdi-account'},

            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleSidebar(){
            this.sidebar = !this.sidebar;
        }
    }
}
</script>

This is the App.vue
<template>
  <v-app v-if="!showAdminNavBar">
    <MyNavBar />
    <v-main>
      <router-view   />
    </v-main>
    <FooterComp />
  </v-app>
  <v-app v-else>
    <AdminNavBar/>
    <v-main>
      <router-view />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import MyNavBar from './components/MyNavBar.vue'
import FooterComp from './components/FooterComp.vue'
import AdminNavBar from './components/AdminPages/layout/AdminNavBar.vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { computed } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    MyNavBar,
    FooterComp,
    AdminNavBar
  },
setup(){
  const route = useRoute();
  const showAdminNavBar = computed(() => route.meta.requiresAdmin)

  return {showAdminNavBar}
},

}
</script>

And this is an example of the AdminDashboard where i want to see the admin navigation : AdminDashboard.vue
<template>
    <div >
      <div >
        <h1>Admin Dashboard</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

<script>
import AdminNavBar from './layout/AdminNavBar.vue';


export default {
    name:"AdminDashboard",
    components: AdminNavBar,
    data(){
        return{

        }
    }
}
</script>

I read that i need to create separate layouts , but i m already far into the code and i cannot refactor that much . Is there another way how to do that . Also if u need something , please ask and i will post other pieces of relevant code if you need

In app.vue you already render different layouts based on route.meta. What is wrong with that approach?

It is not working ..

Could you provide a minimal example in a codesandbox per any chance ?
Also have you tried to put the conditional rendering on the header itself rather than on the App component ?
